# definite integral with limits (both bounds become negative infinity)

Tags: definite-integrals, limits-without-lhopital

I was working on the following definite integral:

$\displaystyle\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{xe^{-x^{2}}}dx$

I decided to use $u$-substitution to make the integral simpler, by letting $u = -x^{2} \Rightarrow du = - 2x\hspace{1 mm}dx$.

The lower bound then becomes $-(-\infty)^{2}=-\infty$, while the upper bound becomes $-\infty^{2} = -\infty$.

So the overall definite integral is then:

$= -\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int^{-\infty}_{\infty}{e^{u}}du$

Which evaluates to:

$= -\dfrac{1}{2} \bigg(e^{-\infty} - e^{-\infty}\bigg)$

$= -\dfrac{1}{2} \times 0$

$= 0$

Is this a legitimate way of doing this problem? Or were there any errors made?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct but the method is sloppy.

Note that $$ \displaystyle\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{xe^{-x^{2}}}dx$$ is defined as $$ \displaystyle\int^{0}_{-\infty}{xe^{-x^{2}}}dx +\displaystyle\int^{\infty}_{0}{xe^{-x^{2}}}dx $$

Now you apply your substitution and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can simply use that for $N>0$
$$
\int_{-N}^{N}xe^{-x^2}\text{d}x=-\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{-N^2}-e^{-N^2}\right)=0
$$
Then taking $\displaystyle N \rightarrow +\infty$ leads you to the result.

I think it is a better approach as $e^{\pm \infty}$ has no sense ( for me )

Note that $\displaystyle \left(-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}\right)'=xe^{-x^2}$.

Comment: In general, this answer is not always applicable.  For example, we cannot use the same argument to say that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xdx = 0$ because both 'halves of the integral diverge.  I would try breaking your problem up into two integrals: one from $-\infty$ to $0$, and one from $0$ to $\infty$.